# How to hide android browser's scroll bar without disabling the scroll functionality?

Tags: javascript, android, css, mobile-browser

I want to hide mobile browser's scroll bar using either css or js.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

This css works on desktop browser chrome, but doesn't work on mobile chrome. When a page is srolled the scroll bar still show up. I wonder if there is a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a css solution but you could use [iSrcoll-4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). It was created to add scrolling functionality to older mobile devices. You can hide the scroll bar it generates by setting vScrollbar to false

```
var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { hScrollbar: false, vScrollbar: false });
```